# How to play 4 gifs one after another in repeat mode as div background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 gifs(because of the length and size issues I had to split the video to make it as 4 gifs instead of 1 single file) and I would like to play all 4 one by one in sequence as a div bg-image in repeat mode only using CSS or Js, is it possible?

For e.g as soon as the page loads play gif1 automatically, once gif1 is completed then play gif2 and gif3 and so on and so forth. Once all 4 gifs are played then start with gif1 again

```
//HTML
<div class="leftsection"></div>
    

//CSS
.leftsection {
   background-image:url("gif1.gif"), url("gif2.gif"), url("gif3.gif"), url("gif4.gif");
   height: 390px;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I tried this and didn't work as expected ;)

Comment: You will need to change the background image using javascript or using CSS animations

Comment: Sorry, may I know how to do it? I am a beginner if you could provide me the more detailed answer would be helpful.

Comment: Short answer: just connect all four gifs into one using a gif maker, e.g. https://ezgif.com/combine .

Comment: @JacobLockwood The problem is - if I combine 4 gifs then it will bring potential experience issues coz one big chunk of gif takes longer to load especially in slow internet connection than 4 small chunks.

Comment: @Praveen hmm... well I don't really see another alternative, as something like `setInterval` in JS will get off sync really fast, and the `animationEnd` event only fires for CSS animations...

Comment: @JacobLockwood hmmm thanks, Jacob :) I will see what else can be done :)